# Array members inside the structure variable

Tags: c, arrays

I have a structure as follows

```
typedef struct s_CanMsg
{
    uint32_t id;
    uint16_t timestamp;
    uint8_t  data[8];
    uint8_t  dlc;
    bool_t   isExtended;
    bool_t   isRemote;
} s_CanMsg_t;
```

and I have a structure variable as follows

```
 s_CanMsg_t CANEraseResponse;
```

Now I am trying to pass an array to the data member of the structure variable as follows:

```
CANEraseResponse.data[8] = {0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

This is showing syntax error and how can I pass the data to the structure variable with array member? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize the whole structure when you define the variable:

```
s_CanMsg_t CANEraseResponse = {
    some_value_for_id,
    some_value_for_timestamp,
    {0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
    some_value_for_dlc,
    some_value_for_isExtended,
    some_value_for_isRemote
};
```

You can also use a designator to explicitly initialize only the array member;

```
s_CanMsg_t CANEraseResponse = {
    .data = {0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}
};
```

Then all other members will be initialized to zero.

And of course you can define a temporary array and copy into the structure array:

```
static uint8_t data[8] = {0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},

s_CanMsg_t CANEraseResponse;
memcpy(CANEraseResponse.data, data, sizeof data);
```

Lastly, if none of the ways above are acceptable, then the only remaining solution is to explicitly assign to each element of the array:

```
CANEraseResponse.data[0] = 0x00;
CANEraseResponse.data[1] = 0xFF;
CANEraseResponse.data[2] = 0x00;
CANEraseResponse.data[3] = 0x04;
CANEraseResponse.data[4] = 0x02;
CANEraseResponse.data[5] = 0x00;
CANEraseResponse.data[6] = 0x00;
CANEraseResponse.data[7] = 0x00;
```

Comment: why cannot we directly initialize an array like following `CANEraseResponse.data[8] = {0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};`

Comment: @user8540390 Because it's not how C is specified to work. And if you see my updated answer then you will hopefully understand why, and what `CANEraseResponse.data[8]` means.

Comment: But we use memcpy in case of pointers and strcpy in case of strings but we can directly initialize arrays like follows right? `int array[5]={1,2,3,4,5}`

Comment: @user8540390 because you cannot initialize what already exists.  It is no longer initialization.

Comment: @user8540390 Variable definition and initialization is something very different from assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The notation you are using can only be used to initialize an array.  Once you declare your struct variable, you have moved past initialization.  You can, however, do it with something called a "designated initializer" like so:

```
s_CanMsg_t CANEraseResponse = {.data= {0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}};
```

Answer (score 0):

`CANEraseResponse.data[8]` refers to the 9th element of the `data` member (as the array is zero based. Try removing the `[8]`.

Edit/Clarification: removing the `[8]` will not solve your issue, but you should be aware that `CANEraseResponse.data[8]` points to a position outside of the `data` array.

Comment: Removing `[8]` won't help. You cannot assign an array to another array.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Still the `data[8]` shows a misconception of how array variables work, so I thought the original poster would benefit from the correction.

Comment: @Marc the misconception is more that the OP is trying to treat it like initialization, like you would, say, `int data[8] = {...};`, rather than attempting to set the value in the 8th position of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign arrays directly in C.  As well as the initialization techniques shown in other answers, you could use a compound literal and `memmove()` (or `memcpy()`):

```
memmove(CANEraseResponse.data, (uint8_t[]){ 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, sizeof(CANEraseResponse.data));
```